# I need help to write my query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table employee like :

```
name  salary
jhon   5000
jaz    5000
raja   1234
rubi   1234
```

I need to get output like

```
  name      salary
  jhon       5000
  raja       1234
```

`NAME` should be anyone (jhon and jaz) OR (raja and rubi) for salary 5000,1234 respectively

Comment: ...And what have you tried so far?  Is there something specific about those particular salaries?  Why are you only reporting one of the people with a given salary?

Comment: Please post some relevant attempts that you've performed in order to find a solution.

Answer (score 4):

There's no way to easily express "any" in SQL - you tend to have to give a rule, even if you don't care.

So,

```
select MIN(Name) as Name,Salary from employee group by salary
```

Will arbitrarily select the `name` that sorts earliest alphabetically.

Answer (score 0):

this is one of the other way of getting result

```
with cte as
( 

select *,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by salary order by name)as rn from table)

select * from cte where rn=2
```

### [fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5f4ab/3)

Answer (score -1):

You Question is quite incomplete including your criteria but see if this suffice your needs

```
select name, Salary from [Employee] where Salary = '5000'
```

will return

jhon   5000 and jaz    5000

```
select name, Salary from [Employee] where Salary = '1234'
```

will return

raja   1234 and rubi   1234